# preg match for this pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to get a link from a preg match but it is not giving any output

Here is pattern:

```
    <a href="http://media1.xyz.com/full5/Animals/Rabbits/rabbits-16a.jpg" download="rabbits-16a"><img onmouseover="showFullScreen('inline')" onmouseout="showFullScreen('none')" src="http://media1.xyz.com/full5/Animals/Rabbits/rabbits-16a.jpg" id="wall" border="0" align="middle"  width="1920" height="1080"  alt="Rabbits 1920x1080 Wallpaper # 17" title="Rabbits HD Wallpaper #17" /></a>
```

I have tried this:

```
     preg_match("/\<a href=/\"(.*)\">/",$str,$title);
```

I want to get the link of href only.

Comment: What is the value of $str?

Comment: You should at least activate error reporting! http://3v4l.org/Y5kiL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$input = '<a href="http://media1.xyz.com/full5/Animals/Rabbits/rabbits-16a.jpg" download="rabbits-16a"><img onmouseover="showFullScreen(\'inline\')" onmouseout="showFullScreen(\'none\')" src="http://media1.xyz.com/full5/Animals/Rabbits/rabbits-16a.jpg" id="wall" border="0" align="middle"  width="1920" height="1080"  alt="Rabbits 1920x1080 Wallpaper # 17" title="Rabbits HD Wallpaper #17" /></a>';

preg_match('/href=\"(.+?)\"/',$input,$title);

echo $title[1];
```

Which will output:

```
http://media1.xyz.com/full5/Animals/Rabbits/rabbits-16a.jpg
```

http://3v4l.org/QnJ9e

Answer (score -1):

Using this match pattern should work

```
'/href=\"(.*?)\"/s'
```

I use it for matching the source in image tags I'm parsing from IMAP emails (in its original form `'/src=\"(.*?)\"/s'` 
But just changing src to href will match for you